# Size in Vectors (C++)

Tags: c++

In C++, using vectors (STL) does size() ALWAYS return the correct amount OCCUPIED elements in a vector?

I checked this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/vector-in-cpp-stl/

Comment: `size()` returns the number of elements in the container. `capacity()` returns the maximum number of elements which can be held prior to reallocation.

Comment: What do you mean with _occupied_? `size` returns the number of elements that you can access while `capacity` returns the number of elements your vector has currently allocated enough memory for.

Comment: @ChrisMM Yes... but is there a case where it does NOT return the correct amount?

Comment: No. Unless the compiler has a bug, which I would highly doubt.

Comment: @n314159 I am unsure what the teacher wanted to ask. Its a practice exam. However, I believe that he is testing the size() function. Will it always return the right# of elements?

Comment: All elements of a vector are *occupied*.

Comment: yes, it will return the number of elements in the vector.

Comment: After being moved from it may not.  You would need to check the exact wording in the standard.

Comment: *Will it always return the right# of elements?* -- If the vector is valid and has not been trashed by the programmer, then the `size()` returns the number of elements.

Comment: Don't use geeksforgeeks.org for anything other than competitive programming. It's not a reliable source.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is what `size()` is specifically for.

From your link:

> size() – Returns the number of elements in the vector.